# Selecting just one the closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with selecting just ONE the closest element by using jQuery.

My HTML code

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>        
            <td>
                <span class="control"><img class="doAction"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>    
            <td class="details">sometext</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to get the text from the `.details` after clicking on the image `.doAction`

But the problem is that I have multiple times this same HTML code, so I want just the closest to this `img` `.details` text to get.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.doAction').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).parents('tr').next().find('.details').text());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h59x88p9/)

Over here, am selecting the parent `tr` of the `img` tag with a `class` of `.doAction` and then am moving on to the next `tr` and searching for an element with `.details`

Note that it's `.parent(s)`, if you want you can also use `.parent()` but then you need to use it thrice, like

```
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find('.details').text();
/*         --^--     --^--    --^--  --^--
  Selects   span      td        tr  goes to next tr and then finds for .details 
                                                            and returns text */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.doAction').click(function(i, e)
{
    e.closest('table').find('.details').html();
});
```

NOTE: Another approach would be to traverse up to the `tr` only, get the next sibling, then get the `.details` from there. This may be more precise as you might have several of these `.doAction` and `.details` elements in there:

```
$('.doAction').click(function(i, e)
{
    e.closest('tr').next().find('.details').html();
});
```

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()` to traverse to table and then find td with `.details` in it:

```
 $('.doAction').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('.details').text();
 });
```